# Python pyparsing file with bracketed strings

Tags: python, text-parsing, pyparsing, brackets

I have a file which contains the following string structures:

```
{dh31100_eurex_internalisation_uat} {DS_REG_PRIMARY} {dh31100} {MMI_PLUGIN_API} {MMI_PLUGIN_API} {20140730}
{ss26879_cc34355_BP_SK_UAT_REGRESSION} {DS_REG_PRIMARY} {dr48750} {MMI_PLUGIN_API} {MMI_PLUGIN_API} {20140730}
{js02041_ba89385_spreads} {DM_SERVER} {ba89385} {MMI_PLUGIN_API} {MMI_PLUGIN_API} {20140731}
{js02041_sc84647_GBP_Analytics} {DS_REG_PRIMARY} {js02041} {MMI_PLUGIN_API} {MMI_PLUGIN_API} {20140721}
...
```

The style is the same across the file, which usually contains > 100 lines.

What would be the best way to create a grammar, given the consistent structure (always 6 sets of brackets), to extract the strings within the brackets and create a list out of them.

The end game would be to perform comparisons between list elements.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Does each line represent one set of data? Is one of the items in each row a useful key for looking up that data?

Comment: Is there ever whitespce inside the `{}`?

Comment: no whitespace inside the {} brackets - but there is a space between the set of brackets if you see above example

Comment: @Robᵩ  Thanks! Each line is one set of data, but each line will be individual and different from the rest. Comparisons will only be made within each line of data. No, there isn't a useful key unfortunately.

Comment: most probably comparisons will be made between element #1 and #3 in list. For example, from the above, third line, comparison would be against {js02041_sc84647_GBP_Analytics} and {js02041}.

Comment: pyparsing seems like the wrong tool here. Do you have some external requirement to use it? [`re`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) is probably a better choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for line in f.readlines():
    line.strip('{}').split('} {')`
```

should convert every line in the file into a list of strings. you can then compare them as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

This will search for a set of `{}`-quoted strings. It will return a list of the list of strings.

```
import re
import sys


# (?<={) = look-behind assertion. Only match if previous token was {
# .*?    = Non-greedy search for any character
# (?=})  = look-ahead assertion. Only match if next token will be }
pattern = '(?<={).*?(?=})'
pattern = re.compile(pattern)

with open(sys.argv[1]) as input_file:
    data = [pattern.findall(line) for line in input_file]

print data
```